# PHP cURL: Max Length on CURLOPT_USERPWD?

Tags: php, curl, basic-authentication

I have a simple GET request in PHP using cURL. It is using basic auth for authentication.

However when the {username}:{password} is longer than 266 characters, it appears to be getting truncated.  I looked everywhere but haven't found any documentation stating this. Is it just me?

```
$data = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

$results = curl_exec($data);

echo $results;

curl_close($data);
```

Comment: I googled for all RCFs and there seems to be no limit on password according to what I have found. +1 for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C expert but I found the following code in the CURL source (!NOT the php extension but the original curl)
Looks like CURL only allocates 256byte for the password.

**EDIT**
Removed the old code, because as Daniel Steinberg stated below this code is not used anymore.

Comment: that is *not* verbatim code from any current libcurl version - but the limit is still 256 as it is a limitation in the libcurl code