# curl always truncates the username after 63 characters

Tags: git, curl, msysgit

I am using the [`_netrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031266/29407) file to store client credentials for basic authentication and noticed that msysgit always truncates the username at the 63rd character.

Here's how my `%HOME%\_netrc` looks like:

```
# username for local repos
machine localhost
login 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345
password secret
```

I have defined a username of 65 characters.

And then I tried to clone a repository:

```
C:\work>git clone https://localhost:44305/git myrepo
```

and here's the output (with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true`):

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
* About to connect() to localhost port 44305 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... * connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 44305 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none
* 0x214a410 is at send pipe head!
* Expire cleared
* SSL connection using AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=localhost
*        start date: 2012-10-23 06:41:25 GMT
*        expire date: 2022-10-23 00:00:00 GMT
*        issuer: CN=localhost
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET /git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.11.msysgit.1
Host: localhost:44305
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm="MyRealm"
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Yzpcd29ya1xUb0REXFdlYkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uMVxXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcZ2l0XGluZm9ccmVmcw==?=
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 13:05:56 GMT
< Content-Length: 4975
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://localhost:44305/git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 44305 (#0)
* 0x214a410 is at send pipe head!
* Server auth using Basic with user '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123☻'
> GET /git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzAjpzZWNyZXQ=
User-Agent: git/1.7.11.msysgit.1
Host: localhost:44305
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Yzpcd29ya1xUb0REXFdlYkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uMVxXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcZ2l0XGluZm9ccmVmcw==?=
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 13:05:56 GMT
< Content-Length: 2
<
* Expire cleared
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 44305 (#0)
* 0x214a410 is at send pipe head!
* Server auth using Basic with user '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123☻'
> GET /git/HEAD HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzAjpzZWNyZXQ=
User-Agent: git/1.7.11.msysgit.1
Host: localhost:44305
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Yzpcd29ya1xUb0REXFdlYkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uMVxXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcZ2l0XEhFQUQ=?=
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 13:05:56 GMT
< Content-Length: 2
<
* Expire cleared
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Notice how msysgit truncated the username at the 63rd character:

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123☻
```

Then I disabled the `_netrc` file and tried to type the username and password interactively but this time I tried entering 256 characters:

```
C:\work>git clone https://localhost:44305/git myrepo
```

and here's the interactive session:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
* Couldn't find host localhost in the _netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to localhost port 44305 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... * connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 44305 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none
* 0x22ea410 is at send pipe head!
* Expire cleared
* SSL connection using AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=localhost
*        start date: 2012-10-23 06:41:25 GMT
*        expire date: 2022-10-23 00:00:00 GMT
*        issuer: CN=localhost
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET /git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.11.msysgit.1
Host: localhost:44305
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

* The requested URL returned error: 401
* Closing connection #0
Username for 'https://localhost:44305': 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456 
Password for 'https://1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456@localhost:44305':
* Couldn't find host localhost in the _netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to localhost port 44305 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... * connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 44305 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none
* SSL re-using session ID
* 0x22ea410 is at send pipe head!
* Expire cleared
* SSL connection using AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=localhost
*        start date: 2012-10-23 06:41:25 GMT
*        expire date: 2022-10-23 00:00:00 GMT
*        issuer: CN=localhost
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET /git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.11.msysgit.1
Host: localhost:44305
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm="GitApi"
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Yzpcd29ya1xUb0REXFdlYkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uMVxXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcZ2l0XGluZm9ccmVmcw==?=
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 13:16:35 GMT
< Content-Length: 4975
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://localhost:44305/git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host localhost in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 44305 (#0)
* 0x22ea410 is at send pipe head!
* Server auth using Basic with user '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345'
> GET /git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1OnNlY3JldA==
User-Agent: git/1.7.11.msysgit.1
Host: localhost:44305
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Yzpcd29ya1xUb0REXFdlYkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uMVxXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcZ2l0XGluZm9ccmVmcw==?=
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 13:16:35 GMT
< Content-Length: 2
<
* Expire cleared
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Couldn't find host localhost in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 44305 (#0)
* 0x22ea410 is at send pipe head!
* Server auth using Basic with user '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345'
> GET /git/HEAD HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1OnNlY3JldA==
User-Agent: git/1.7.11.msysgit.1
Host: localhost:44305
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Yzpcd29ya1xUb0REXFdlYkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uMVxXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcZ2l0XEhFQUQ=?=
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 13:16:35 GMT
< Content-Length: 2
<
* Expire cleared
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

This time the username was truncated at the 255th character.

I have tried using msysgit under a standard MS-DOS prompt as well as a PowerShell prompt and a Git Bash prompt with the same results.

So here are my questions:

1. Is this some limitation of msysgit?
2. Could this limit be increased (both for the `_netrc` file and the interactive prompt)?
3. Are there any workarounds?

And if you ask why do I need such long usernames, well, it's because my goal is to send OAuth tokens for a custom GIT server, the same way GitHub does it (except that their OAuth tokens are pretty short).

---

UPDATE:

Further investigating it seems that the problem is with [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) which is what GIT uses for HTTP client. I am able to reproduce the exact same behavior with the following command:

```
curl --netrc -kv https://localhost:44305/git
```

So am retaging the question.

---

UPDATE 2:

Further investigating in [`netrc.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/curl/curl-57/curl/lib/netrc.c):

```
/* make sure we have room for at least this size: */
#define LOGINSIZE 64
#define PASSWORDSIZE 64
```

I am starting to lose my optimism for a good outcome from this.

Comment: My guess is that the reason GitHub uses short tokens is exactly what you found above ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it seems to be limitation of curl. The code you're referencing is not current: [this, I think, is](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/netrc.h), and has the same values.

For windows, cygwin version of git fixes some limitations that msysgit has, such as path size limit. However, as this is a limitation of curl and not msysgit, there's not much it can do, and indeed when I tested there was the same behaviour.

Note though that this seems to be a limitation of .netrc file usage, as [neither HTTP spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027825/is-there-a-maximum-length-for-a-http-basic-authentication-username) or [curl programmatic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617278/php-curl-max-length-on-curlopt-userpwd) has that limit. Indeed, if you just specify it in the url, it seems to work:

```
C:\REMenu>git remote add origin https://1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890@github.com/romaonthego/REMenu.git

C:\REMenu>git push origin master
...
* Server auth using Basic with user '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'
..
Password for 'https://1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
901234567890@github.com':
```

If you need to use _netrc, I think your only option is to compile curl yourself if you need this to work.

If you don't have to, you do have other options:

- running a local proxy that specifies user/pass for you, and using that proxy when connecting, specifying no user/pass for git or curl
- using username in the url
- using ssh-based urls

---

Edit: just to recap, limits we've seen so far:

- _netrc: 64 (curl .netrc limit)
- interactive: 256
- credential.helper wincred: 512 (windows credential store limit)
- credential.helper plain: 4000+
- url: 4000+
- proxy: unlimited (should only be limited by HTTP and proxy software)

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming my suspicions. Indeed sending the username in the url doesn't suffer from this limitation. The problem I have with this is that my token could contain arbitrary characters and I don't know how to properly encode them in the url. Compiling cURL myself is absolutely out of question as well as using a local proxy. Do you have any idea how to properly encode the username in the url (assuming that it could already contain characters such as `:`, `@`, `=`, ...)?

Comment: If this is for Git usage only maybe the git-credentials support can help you. Using either wincred or winstore provides a separate mechanism for storing credentials using the Windows credentials API so somewhat more secure than a .netrc file. I've not tested the limits but possibly these provide for larger user ids. Using wincred is as simple as `git config --global credential.helper wincred`. Once you get asked for login details for an https url this helper stores them in the backing store for reuse another time.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov standard url encoding applies to username & password too, if they are used as part of the url scheme

Comment: I am trying the windows credentials store method. It looks very promising. I am unable to make it work just yet but once I do I will post an update and accept your answer.

Comment: The Windows Credential Store worked wonderfully. Thanks for your valuable support. Much appreciated.

Comment: Taking my words back. Usernames in the Windows Credential Store are limited to 512 characters. This is annoying.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov it might be beneficial to specify (in the question, also) how long usernames you actually need

Comment: @DarinDimitrov ok. Tested that with the username-in-url approach, so at least that is possible, seems to be working.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov also credential.helper store seems to be working with 4000+ chars username - that's not very safe as it stores the username in plain text, but at least it works. so you'd have a git config entry like `[credential "https://hostname.com/"] username = 4000charsoftext`